# Android SharedPreference security

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences

I wonder about shared preferences security.

Is it possible to get access to sharedpreferences, even if they were created in MODE_PRIV (0) ?
Is it possible to list all sharedpreferences available and then fetch all settings from other apps?
Is sharedpreferences good place to put sensitive data, such as password or auth token?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How secure are SQLite and SharedPreferences files on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608883/how-secure-are-sqlite-and-sharedpreferences-files-on-android)

Comment: Worth a look, with nice answers. Shared preferences says a lot about programming style of the developer.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Shared Preferences are stored as a file in the filesystem on the device. They are, by default, stored within the app's data directory with filesystem permissions set that only allow the UID that the specific application runs with to access them. So, they are private in so much as Linux file permissions restrict access to them, the same as on any Linux/Unix system.

Anyone with root level access to the device will be able to see them, as root has access to everything on the filesystem. Also, any application that runs with the same UID as the creating app would be able to access them (this is not usually done and you need to take specific action to make two apps runs with the same UID, so this is probably not a big concern). Finally, if someone was able to mount your device's filesystem without using the installed Android OS, they could also bypass the permissions that restrict access.

If you're concerned about such access to your preferences (or any data written by your application), then you will want to encrypt it. If you are that concerned about them, you're going to need to figure out exactly how much protection is necessary for the level of risk you see. There is a very extensive discussion about this in [Application Security for the Android Platform](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022596.do), just published in December 2011 (disclaimer: I'm the author of this book).

Comment: Is there any official documentation that talks about this? Do you have any references?

Comment: did you mean encrypt before store both encrypted data and encryption key in shared prefs?

Answer (score 32):

SharedPreferences are nothing but XML files in your phones /data/data/ folder,So any application or user with superuser privilages on a rooted device can access your SharedPreferences, even if they were created with MODE_PRIV

Still **there is a way to protect it** from everybody...
Please checkout this link.
Here you can store data in pref with encryption,the class is self explanatory and very easy to use.

https://github.com/sveinungkb/encrypted-userprefs

As said by others anyone can access it but in this case no one can read data inside it as it is encrypted. So its secure.For **Utmost** security my suggestion will be to generate the key used for encryption at run time rather than hard coding it. There are many ways to do that :)

Comment: then how do you save the generated key?

Comment: @Olayinka It'd be safer to encrypt that with yet another key and save it in a `SharedPref`. But then, what to do with the other key? Seriously though, best scenario would be sending the encrypted key and a device UID to a server using SSL to be stored there and retrieved as needed. That would require connectivity, but would allow you to blacklist a device and suddenly have all data trashed. Without constant internet connection, any try to encrypt data is not 100% safe.

Comment: I used the above solution...it works 9 out of 10 times..but I am getting error:1e06b065:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:BAD_DECRYPT" at times..Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: @PauloAvelar Use Android KeyStore for long term storage and retrieval of cryptographic keys. Keys are not stored within an application, so they cannot be compromised. Provided library does not use it. It saves the secret in the code thus it is not safe.

Comment: @apex39 You may not be addressing the scenario for when the device is rooted, but just to make sure. The use of the KeyStore does **not** protect against root. You are right (in the case of a physically backed KeyStore) that the keys cannot be compromised. However, root can still request that the KeyStore decrypt the previously encrypted data, making any data previously encrypted with it compromised.

Answer (score 16):

Normally, no, they cannot be accessed by other apps, however, you should note that SharedPreferences are stored as XML files in the `/data/data/` directory, which essentially means that *any* application with *superuser privileges* on a *rooted* device *can* access your `SharedPreference`s, even if they were created with `MODE_PRIV`

Answer (score 5):

***Is it possible to get access to sharedpreferences, even if they were created in MODE_PRIV (0) ?***

By code No. But you can retrieve application file if you have super user privileged.

***Is it possible to list all sharedpreferences available and then fetch all settings from other apps?***

If you are super user(rooted devices) then you can pull all private files of the app.

***Is sharedpreferences good place to put sensitive data, such as password or auth token?***

No. It can be easily hacked. If you want to put any sensitive data in shared prefrence file you can encrypt the data and store. You can store your encryption key in NDK/server.

Comment: How can it be easily hacked?

Comment: Yes the question form @Jo

Comment: @JohnSardinha I believe you can just edit the XML file as soon as you have write access to it. Then after restarting the app, the modified file will be used.