# Android SharedPreference save sensitive data

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to figure out a good way to store logged-in user data.

I'm thinking of saving the user-id into the SharedPreference "MODE_PRIVATE".

My questions is, if a user create an account with the id of 1. Is it possible to tamper with the APK and change the value to be 2? This way when he re-opens the application he can be falsely logged in as user 2?

If yes, i would love to get an explanation and ideas for better solutions to counter that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244620/3830694 and http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-hacking-security-part-12-securing-shared-preferences-third-party-libraries/

Comment: Thanks, this answers my is it secure part. I guess it is not. Anyone with a rooted phone can read and change the value. Any better solutions?

Comment: better solution would be that you save encrypted data.

Comment: There will be always options to make evil, encrypt your sensitive data (and there will still be options...)