# Remove some SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am making a simple slashing game and I am saving stuffs like gold
in `SharedPreferences`. How to remove it from `SharedPreferences` 
but still be able to call the value of the gold,like Temple run 2 game.

Answer (score 1):

To remove specific values: `SharedPreferences.Editor.remove()` followed by a `commit()`

To remove them all `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a `commit()`

If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from your application's main thread, consider using apply() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

and then read from Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

And also dont forget to get a handle

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: This is exactly all that is required to work with SharedPreferences, However, I would argue that you should tell people to use apply() instead of commit() just because

Comment: how do you hide the high score? its still visible in the location of the sharedpreferences in client's android

Comment: I think this answer fits the bill, but you should post your solution and let the OP decide which is more useful to them

Comment: there is no "hide", you can overwrite if with Null. If you want to store the gold in a way it is not seen in the shared preferences then you must save it in a cloud. Is this the case? Do you want to prevent users to manipulate it?

Comment: yes I want to prevent users to manipulate it but in offline not with server

Comment: have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244620/6615718) and then evalutate about your implementation work

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your sp name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sp.edit().remove("gold").commit();// remove gold
    sp.edit().clear().commit();//remove all
```