# Android Notification from an app to only specific user

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I want to build an Android app which will track the attendance of the users.So, each user will have an account with username and password and there will a manager who can view the attendance details of every user from the database.So everyday, when the users login to their account and enters the attendance for the day, if a user marks himself as absent for the day,then a notification needs to be sent "Only to the Manager" by the app that the user will be absent for the day.And that notification will be coming from the server when the users marks himself as Absent.Can anyone please let me know how to proceed?I am new to Android.

Comment: Can you know on login if the person who is logging in is manager?

Comment: Does the manager also have a login?

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari yeah,the manager will be given a specific username and password.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari yes,manager also has a login.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use **SharedPreferences**

When you login store if it's a manager login or not:

```
private final String KEY_PREF_NAME = "UserInfoSettings", 
KEY_IS_MANAGER = "KEY_IS_MANAGER";

private SharedPreferences mPref = getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mPref.edit()
                .putBoolean(KEY_IS_MANAGER, value)
                .commit();
```

value = true or false

When you get the notification check if the logged in person is a manager:

```
if(mPref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_MANAGER, false)){
//TODO show notification
}
```

On logout clear the preferences:

```
mPref.edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: No problem, because clearing app data will also logout the user. So to use the app he will have to login again and SHaredPreferences will be created again.

Comment: Do you think it's a safe way to save the manager login  data locally ?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244318/android-sharedpreference-security).

Comment: Also you can use encryption on the value if you want it secured from rooted devices as well.

Comment: Thank you , It's a great answer also the book provided is important https://ht.transparencytoolkit.org/rcs-dev%5Cshare/HOME/MarcoL/books/Application%20Security%20for%20the%20Android%20Platform.pdf

Comment: Most welcome! Mark my answer as accepted if it helped! That'll be appreciated! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138517/discussion-between-arolaab-and-aishwarya-tiwari).

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari I will try to build the app with your approach.Thanks for the help:)

Comment: I guess filtering the users on the server side is better from do it on each app , what if you hava 10 000 users and you have a slow server , the server need to send 10 000 notififcations and the app will need to do an additional work to check the shared preference and see if the notification should be showing  .

Comment: Definitely server has all data so it should be sending notifications to the manager only.

Comment: why you need a shared preference then if you know can reach the manager only ?

Comment: @ArolaAb can you please explain a little bit on how to filter the users on server side? What I was thinking is to create a username and password for each user and also a username and password for the manager.

Comment: As I say in my answer you can use firebase , you can store a login data like a database and let the fierbase server send the notification for you , also every device have a unique mac address and a unique IMEI..

Comment: @ArolaAb if you doing server side then no need to handle it device side obviously.

Comment: I edit my answer , @AishwaryaTiwari i think your answer isn't the best option here , using firebase is better.

Comment: @ArolaAb Actually I am new to Android and I have never used Firebase before. I will try to learn and implement your idea if this approach does not work out. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help as much as possible. :)

Answer (score 2):

What if the user mark himself not absent and he is not even in the school ?

Anw you can check  [Firebase Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/)

> Firebase is a mobile and web application platform with tools and infrastructure designed to help developers build high-quality apps. Firebase is made up of complementary features that developers can mix-and-match to fit their needs.

**Edit**

> With Firebase Notifications, you can target notifications to a single, specific device. You'll need access to the registration token for the app instance on that device, in order to provide the token when composing and sending the notification in the Notifications console.

Please check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device) and you will get it!

Comment: Each user will be getting a notification in the morning to fill his/her attendance.So,it is mandatory for each user to mark their attendance everyday. And the attendance for each day will be recorded in the database, so that if at the end of the month,the manager wants to check for how many days did a specific user not come,then he can view from the database.

Comment: Yeah , but what if the user have not came to school and mark himself present for a lecture ?

Comment: Actually I am trying to build this app for 7 users now.So,if any user has not come and marked himself/herself as "Present", then the manager will be able to catch him/her cheating.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Will surely go through the provided documentation. :)